# Is there an easy way to see a log of SCP activity on a server (ala /var/log/secure for ssh login)?

Tags: ssh, logging, forensics, selinux

On Linux systems, `/var/log/secure`  (or similar, depending on distro) shows all SSH login activity.  Is there a similar log for SCP?  If not, what's a good approach to enabling logging of scp activity on my servers?  Is it SELinux through /var/log/audit/audit.log?

Answer (score 8):

You need to adjust your sshd logging level to DEBUG in order to see scp client connections.

Look at the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the "LogLevel" directive.

```
LogLevel DEBUG
```

Or the `scp -o LogLevel` for testing.

Answer (score 0):

SCP uses SSH connections to transfer files, so SCP logins should appear in the same logs alongside SSH logins. From the [man pages](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1):

> scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for data
>        transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security
>        as ssh(1).

Comment: I know it uses SSH and I thought logs would also go to the same place, but it actually doesn't show up in /var/log/secure nor /var/log/messages.  The only evidence of SCP is when I have SELinux and auditd running... in which case it gets logged in /var/log/audit/audit.log.

Answer (score -4):

```
scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG <rest of parameters>
```

eg:

```
$ scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG origfile.txt userfoo@serverbar:/home/userfoo/
```

Comment: This is already in the top-voted answer. Note that this does *not* show you the scp activity for the server but the log for that connection. Please make sure that you document your code/commands instead of just posting raw syntax without explanation.